# How can i Start/Stop this JavaScript Whitebaord using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, frontend

The problem here is that the this Code instantly draws when i move in the Canvas.
But it should Only Draw **while** i "MouseDown" and stop when i "Mouseup".

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

function draw(canvas, event) {


  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5)
}

    canvas.onmousemove = (e)=>{
        draw(canvas, e)
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please add a [mre] to your question to receive faster, better responses from the community

Answer (score 0):

Register `mousedown` event on canvas and `mouseup` event on window. The event handler just need to store which buttons are pressed and in your draw `mousemove` event handler draw only if variable with buttons is not 0:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

function draw(canvas, event) {


  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5)
}

canvas.onmousemove = (e)=>{
  if (buttons)
    draw(canvas, e)
}

let buttons = 0; //1 = left, 2 = right, 4 = middle
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => buttons = e.buttons);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", e => buttons = e.buttons);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```